# How to use hover speed with multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with understanding slowing down the hover speed. I have a script set up to move multiple properties (`mejs__speed-button`,`mejs__time-rail`) when you hover over an element `mejs__group-volume` and need to set up some way to slow down the changes.

My JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.mejs__group-volume').hover(
function () {
$('.mejs__horizontal-volume-slider').css({"display":"block"});
$('.mejs__speed-button button').css({"margin":"21px 0 0 -50px"});
$('.mejs__time-slider').css({"width":"-moz-calc(100% - 91px)","width":"-webkit-calc(100% - 91px)","width":"calc(100% - 91px)"});
$('.mejs__duration-container').css({"margin-right":"94.5px"});
},
function () {
$('.mejs__horizontal-volume-slider').css({"display":"none"});
$('.mejs__speed-button button').css({"margin":"21px 30px 0 41px"});
$('.mejs__time-slider').css({"width":"100%"});
$('.mejs__duration-container').css({"margin-right":"3.5px"});
});});
```

URL to see code in action: http://wpfreelance.bayoumedia.net/audio/

Comment: CSS transitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use js animate function​ or css transitions

See: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp